# "invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) token" on some routes

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I get this error when submitting a form. The form does have a hidden _csrf_token field, as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

However, when it is submitted, the token fails validation:

```
[debug] ** (Plug.CSRFProtection.InvalidCSRFTokenError) invalid CSRF (Cross Site Request 
Forgery) token, make sure all requests include a valid '_csrf_token' param or 
'x-csrf-token' header
    (plug) lib/plug/csrf_protection.ex:233: Plug.CSRFProtection.call/2
```

My code is pretty standard:

**router.ex**

```
scope "/account" do
  pipe_through :browser

  get "/redeem/:token", MyAppWeb.Accounts.AccountController, :verify_invitation
  post "/redeem", MyAppWeb.Accounts.AccountController, :redeem_invitation
end
```

**account_controller.ex**

```
#renders the form
def verify_invitation(conn, %{"token" => token}) do
  conn
  |> put_status(:ok)
  |> put_flash(:info, "Invitation verified. Please choose a password.")
  |> put_view(MyAppWeb.Accounts.AccountView)
  |> render("redeem.html", invitation: invitation)
end

#simplified
def redeem_invitation(conn, %{"token" => token, "user" => %{"password" => password, "password_confirmation" => password_confirmation}}) do
  conn
  |> redirect(external: MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers.login_page_url(conn, MyAppWeb.Endpoint, :new) <> "?action=redeem")
end
```

**redeem.html.eex**

```
<%= form_for @conn, redeem_invitation_path(@conn, :redeem_invitation), fn f -> %>

  # stuff

  <%= submit "Create Account", class: "btn btn-indigo ml-0" %>

<% end %>
```

Why is the CSRF token failing to validate?

Comment: Just to be sure, try to remove the `_build` directory, and see if that helps? As well as testing the app in incognito mode.

Comment: Neither of those suggestions worked.

Comment: Try removing `put_status(:ok)`

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to have a second pipe_through :browser in your router.ex? If so that could be causing the issue.

Comment: If that is the case, how would I debug it?

Comment: @Tronathan you can check your router for nested scopes as a possible culprit.